# Matrix of a endomorphism mapping a basis to another

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional real vector space, and let $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}, B'=\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ be two different basis of $V$. Let $f:V\to V$ be an endomorphism such that, for every $i=1,\ldots,n$, it holds that $f(v_i)=w_i$.

*Question:* Let $M_{B',B}(f)$ be the matrix associated to $f$ from the basis $B$ to the basis $B'$. Is it true that $M_{B'.B}(f)=I_n$, with $I_n$ the identity matrix?

I guess so, however writing down an explicit example it seems wrong (but I'm probably doing something wrong, I haven't computed these in years).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on what exactly you mean with the notation $M_{B',B}(f)$, but you're probably using the notation where the first variable in the subscript denotes the basis of the domain. If that's the case, then yes, that is correct.

Comment: Typically, when one regards endomorphisms, the constraint is applied that the same basis should be used for both the "domain" and "codomain" since both domain and codomain are the same space $V$. Two matrices corresponding to the same endomorphism under this constraint are "similar", but the same cannot be said when you're allowed to use two different bases.

Comment: Dear @Ben Grossmann, thanks for the fast reply! In my notation $M_{B',B}(f)$ I mean that $B'$ is the basis of the codomain, and $B$ is the basis of the domain, so I go from $B$ to $B'$.

Comment: Regarding the second reply: I see, thanks for the clarification. Anyway, could you please provide a proof for the question, so that I can see, upvote and accept it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I said the opposite of what I meant. Yes, your result is consistent with your convention

Comment: I’ll leave a proof if I get the chance and no one beats me to it

Answer (score 1):

Let $m_{ij}$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ denote the entries of the matrix $M_{B',B}(f)$. In general, this matrix is defined such that if $v_j$ is the $j$th element of $B$ and $w_i$ the $i$th element of $B$, then
$$
f(v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^m m_{ij} w_i = m_{1j}w_1 + m_{2j} w_2 + \cdots + m_{nj}w_n.
$$
In other words, $f(v_j)$ determines the $j$th column of $M_{B',B}(f)$. With that, we note that for your particular $f$ we have for all $1 \leq j \leq n$
$$
f(v_j) = w_j =  \\
0\cdot w_1 + \cdots + 0\cdot w_{j-1} + 1\cdot w_j + 0\cdot w_{j+1} + \cdots + 0\cdot w_n.
$$
(The above notation does not strictly make sense in the case where $j = 1$ or $j = n$, but I hope you see the general pattern). Thus, we can conclude that the $j$ column of the matrix is the $j$th column of the identity matrix. Thus, $M_{B',B}$ is indeed the identity matrix.